# c# efficient way of reading arrays of specific type from stream

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm looking for an efficient way of reading multiple arrays of a specific type from a stream.

So far I'm using a class like this below to read single values like: *int, byte, sbyte, uint, short, ushort, ...*
but also for arrays like: *ushort[], short[], uint[], int[], byte[], sbyte[], ...*

```
    public byte[] ReadBytes(int count)
    {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[count];
      int retValue = _Stream.Read(buffer, 0, count);
      return buffer;
    }

    public ushort ReadUshort()
    {
      byte[] b = ReadBytes(2);
      if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) // for motorola (big endian)
        Array.Reverse(b);
      return BitConverter.ToUInt16(b, 0);
    }

    public ushort[] ReadUshorts(int count) 
    {
       ushort[] data = new ushorts[count];
       for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       {
          data[i] = ReadUshort();
       }
       return data;
    }

   public uint ReadUint() 
   {
       byte[] b = ReadBytes(4);
      if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) // for motorola (big endian)
        Array.Reverse(b);
      return BitConverter.ToUInt32(b, 0);
   }

   public uint[] ReadUints(int count)
   {
      // ...
   }
```

Is there a more efficient way compared to code snippet I've shared here to read the arrays?

I have a feeling that a combination of for-loop and each time a single read call is not so efficient. But the problem is that I need to check for IsLittleEndian each time and reverse if needed, so I can read many bytes at ones. Not sure if this could be rewritten more efficiently.

Comment: You can always optimize, for example, if ReadUshorts implements the logic of ReadUshort, you can read all data at once. But you will lose in maintenance. Is it critical for your use case?

Comment: well I rather have a bit harder code but faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a generic method, and use `Buffer.BlockCopy` to copy the data into the target array:

```
    public static T[] ReadElements<T>(Stream input, int count)
    {
        int bytesPerElement = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesPerElement * count];

        int remaining = buffer.Length;
        int offset = 0;
        while (remaining > 0)
        {
            int read = input.Read(buffer, offset, remaining);
            if (read == 0) throw new EndOfStreamException();
            offset += read;
            remaining -= read;
        }

        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i += bytesPerElement)
            {
                Array.Reverse(buffer, i, bytesPerElement);
            }
        }

        T[] result = new T[count];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, result, 0, buffer.Length);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: this looks like a clean method, I'm only wondering if there is a way to directly read bigendian/littleendian instead of having a possible extra for-loop for array.reverse ?

Comment: I was wondering this too, but in the end _something_ is going to have to loop over the bytes to swap them. `Array.Reverse` is not the fastest solution, but it can deal with the different data sizes of the generic type this way.